# Google Drive API - Compound Permissions on Files

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to have compound permissions on files? For example, I'd like User A to have writer access until a set date, then after that date they can only comment (or view) the file. Right now as I'm testing on my personal files, the API explorer doesn't show all the permissions I have set.

Comment: I think what you want to achieve is not possible if you considered or based on the Google Drive API documentation. Just read the provided link by DaImTo to know more about [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions), and the things that you can do to it.

Comment: @KENdi Given the current design I was hoping that this would be doable; guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Directly though the API you can set the roll and type of access each user has your application would have to remove it after said date.

You could try reading the documentation: [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Comment: No, I want them to compound, i.e. add multiple permissions to the same file for the same user, of which each permission has its own expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the `expirationTime` field in the permission resource

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions

You can create a permission, that will expire at the defined moment.

So for your task, you can create two permissions one for reading and commenting without expiration time, and another for writing with expiration time.

Comment: Oh, this is just a repetition of the suggestion from @tyteen4a03